# How to arrange these three items in Android

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to have a horizontal scroll bar aligned at the top (containing buttons) and then a relative layout after that (which can contain whatever I put in there) and then a final horizontal scroll bar aligned at the bottom. How do I force the horizontal scroll bars to be fixed to the top/bottom and then have the relative layout in the middle stretch to everything else in between?

Comment: can you post screenshot or wireframe or code

Comment: You can use partition of this layout lik use of layout_weight=""

Comment: I want the top and bottom to have height wrapping their contents, but the center relative layout to span everything in between

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using LinearLayout...

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:gravity="center">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/top_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/middle_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"></RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Using RelativeLayout....

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/top_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"></RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/middle_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/top_container"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottom_container"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: The `android:layout_height="0dp" / android:layout_weight="1"` is what I had been missing. How is this different from using match_parent or wrap_content? How come that works?

Comment: okay, so your top container and bottom container height is wrap_content, it will only take the height required by their childs, and by specifying weight =1 and height= 0dp in middle container, it will take the remaining height.

Comment: Same thing you can achieve in width, by giving properties as width = "0dp" and weight = "1".

Answer (score 0):

You can use `layout_weight` inside of a `LinearLayout` to have it expand to fill the layout.

For example:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <!-- Buttons -->
    </HorizontalScrollView>
    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        <!-- Content -->
    </RelativeLayout>
    <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <!-- More Buttons -->
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Post your wireframe so that we can help better. However I think probably your solution is :-**
Keep your main layout a RelativeLayout.Take another LinearLayout under your main layout with orientation vertical.Place your horizontal scrollview and other items in LinearLayout and outside that LinearLayout, keep your horizontal scrollview with this attribute  :

> android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

Your xml will look like this:

```
<RelativeLayout>
  <LinearLyout>
    // horizontal scrollview
    // other items
  </LinearLayout>
    // horizaontal scrollview with alignparentbottom="true"
</RelativeLAyout>
```